# Javascript function implementation variation

Tags: javascript, function

If i need to write a java script function that takes an argument and returns a function that returns that argument, i can think of following two implementations. Are both of these same ? or there is anything different technically ? Both works and returns the same result.

```
/*Implemenation 1*/
function myWieredFunc(arg){
    var retf=function inner(){
        return arg;
    };
    return retf;
}

/* Implemenation 2 */
function myWieredFunc(arg){
    return function(){
        return arg;
    };
}
```

To use these:

```
 var f = myWieredFunc(84);       
 alert(f());
```

Comment: It does the same thing. You don't need the variable.

Comment: And even in the first example, you don't need to name the inner function ("inner") at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for the variable in the code shown - functions are objects are values. As you've shown this means that function-objects can be assigned to a variable which is later evaluated and returned, or returned directly from the Function Expression.

As such, both forms are generally held equivalent and the closure over `arg` is unaffected.

*However, in the first form..*

1. `Function.toString` and stack-traces will normally include the function name, this makes "named functions", as in the first example sometimes more useful in debugging. Additionally, Firefox will expose function names - e.g. "inner" - through the *non-standard* `Function.name` property. (The function name can be specified without the use of the `retf` variable.)
2. Two additional bindings are introduced - `retf` in the outer function and `inner` in the inner function. These variables *could* be observed in the the applicable scope when stopping via a break-point - but are not otherwise accessible in the code shown.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the way to write it

```
function wrap(arg) {
    return function() {
        return arg;
    };
};
```

If you wanted to make it more flexible you could allow multiple arguments:

```
function wrap() {
    var args = arguments;
    return function() {
        return args;
    };
};

var later = wrap('hello', 'world');
var result = later();
console.log(result); // ["hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing, the second is using an "Anonymous" function which just means its a function that is not given a name or assigned to a variable.